# Minimum and maximum size with percentages

Tags: html, css

I have this html code bellow representing a small panel, this panel should be set to any type of screen, but it has the following rule:

> When the resolution is 800x600 or lower it stops to adjust (stay with 800x600), when the screen
>   resolution is 4K (4096x2160) or higher it stops to adjust (stay with 4096x2160).

in this cade the minimal resolution is 800x600 and the max resolution is 4096x2160. For that I try this code:

```
<div id="topo" style="background:#EEEEEE; border:1px solid #BBBBBB; height:10%; width:100%; border-radius:5px; position: relative; min-width:923px; min-height:88px; max-width:1908px; max-height:110px;">

</div>

<div style="float:left; width:100%; min-width:923px; max-width:1920px; height:90%; max-height:1080px; min-height:720px;">

<div id="Menu_B" style="background:#EEEEEE; text-align:center; border:1px solid #BBBBBB; max-width:764px; max-height:428px; min-height:401px; height:44.1%; width:40%; min-width:370px; border-radius:5px; position: relative; margin-top:5px; float: left; text-align:center; ">

</div>


<div id="Menu_left" style="background:#EEEEEE; text-align:center; border:1px solid #BBBBBB; max-width:1125px; max-height:861px; height:89%; min-height:805px; width:59.2%; border-radius:5px; font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif; position: relative; margin-top:5px; float:right; min-width:547px;">

</div>

<div id="Menu_C" style="background:#EEEEEE; text-align:center; border:1px solid #BBBBBB; max-width:764px; max-height:428px; min-height:401px; height:44.1%; width:40%; min-width:370px; border-radius:5px; position: relative; margin-top:5px; float: left;">
</div>

</div>
```

And you can test it in this [Website](http://jsfiddle.net/xtaxjnff/4/), I think the problem is in **max-width, max-height, min-width, min-height** that are in pixels mode instead of percentages, right? Need javascript to do that?

How can I solve this design problem and put that idea to work?

Comment: the divs inside the viewport have to be fluid not the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, stop inline CSS properties into HTML and move them to CSS file.

Than you can use [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) which allows you to have the separate rules for the various screen resolutions.

So, your CSS should look like the following:

```css
.typo {
  background:#EEEEEE;
  border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
  border-radius:5px;
  height:10%;
  max-height:110px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)
{
 .typo {
  min-width: 800px;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 4096px) 
{
 .typo {
  max-width: 4096px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="topo" class='typo'>Typo text</div>
```

Try to run this code in the full screen; resize the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the dimensions of the `div`s to percentages.  Then you just need to set the width and height of the `body` element.  You can use [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerWidth) to constrain its dimensions.

```
var body= document.querySelector('body');
if(window.innerWidth < 800) {
  body.style.cssText= 'width:800px;height:600px';
}
else if(window.innerWidth > 4096) {
  body.style.cssText= 'width:4096px;height:2160px';
}
```

### Fiddle